# Collaborating Typhoon assemblies results in "Can't find assembly of type" info log message

Tags: typhoon

I've been using Typhoon in my app for a while. After a recent upgrade to Typhoon v3.2.8, I've been getting a new info-level message logged into the console on app launch:

> 2015-09-04 15:27:07.761 MYApp[1348:10138960] -[TyphoonAssembly
>   activateWithFactory:collaborators:][Line 280] [info] *** Warning ***
>   Can't find assembly of type MYCoreAssembly. Is this intentional? The
>   property 'coreAssembly' in class MYApplicationAssembly will be left as
>   nil.

In my app, Typhoon is Info.plist activated, with two collaborating assemblies: `MYApplicationAssembly` and `MYCoreAssembly`.

My app delegate has several Typhoon-injected properties, including the `MYApplicationAssembly` instance. The `MYApplicationAssembly` implementation "collaborates with" the `MYCoreAssembly` assembly. The relevant interface declarations are:

```
@interface MYApplicationAssembly : TyphoonAssembly

@property (nonatomic, readonly) MYCoreAssembly *coreAssembly;

- (MYHomeViewController *)homeViewController;

@end
```

```
@interface MYCoreAssembly : TyphoonAssembly

- (id)someCoreThing;

@end
```

I'd like to figure out what the underlying cause of the warning message above is, and if it's not actually an issue (everything continues to work as expected), then how to silence it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug. As far is we know it doesn't cause any other issues, nonetheless we will fix ASAP.

Comment: The issue was marked as closed in 3.3.3, I've reopened it: https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/issues/408

Comment: Update: Looks fixed in 3.3.3, above commend was due to error on my end.